# How to edit data in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, edit

I want to edit lecturer data with laravel. however, I got a 404 not found error.
Here is the route that I used

```
Route::controller(DosenController::class)
    ->prefix('dosen')
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'index')->name('dosen.index');
        Route::get('/tambah', 'create')->name('dosen.create');
        Route::post('/tambah', 'store')->name('dosen.store');
        Route::get('/detail/{id}', 'show')->name('dosen.detail');
        Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('dosen.edit');
        Route::put('/edit/{id}', 'update')->name('dosen.update');
        Route::delete('/hapus/{id}', 'destroy')->name('dosen.delete');
        Route::get('pdf', 'exportpdf')->name('dosen.pdf');
    });
```

this is the lecturer controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $dosen = Dosen::findOrFail($id);
        dd($id);
        return view('dosen.edit', compact('dosen'));
    }
```

this is the view

```
<button class="action" style="background: #ff8200">
     <a href="{{ route('dosen.edit', $dosen->id) }}" style="color: inherit">
        <i class='bx bxs-edit'></i>
        Edit
     </a>
</button>
```

I have done a die and dump. However, got an error 404 message. What should i do? Shall i change the model too?

Comment: The 404 comes either before it hits the controller, or on the `findOrFail`, so it never reaches the `dd()`. What does the URL say at the top? If you move the `dd()` one line up, do you get the value?

Comment: You can try [Route Model Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#route-model-binding) too: `Route::get('/edit/{dosen}', ...);`, then `public function edit(Dosen $dosen) { dd($dosen); }`, and lastly `{{ route('doesn.edit', $dosen) }}`.

Comment: can you share the your project url with pass route name

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/edit-data{id}', [crudcontroller::class, 'editData']);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply

Answer (score 0):

Your line causes a 404 error `$dosen = Dosen::findOrFail($id);`. Look inside the `findOrFail` method and you'll see. To change the situation, use, for example, the `find` method, and then use the `if` method to handle it as you need.

```php
public function findOrFail($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    $result = $this->find($id, $columns);

    $id = $id instanceof Arrayable ? $id->toArray() : $id;

    if (is_array($id)) {
        if (count($result) !== count(array_unique($id))) {
            throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
                get_class($this->model), array_diff($id, $result->modelKeys())
            );
        }

        return $result;
    }

    if (is_null($result)) {
        throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
            get_class($this->model), $id
        );
    }

    return $result;
}
```